# How to make a custom toast layout to really fill fullscreen in Android?

Tags: android, android-toast

I face a little problem with my custom toast design in my Android app.

I defined the toast XML like so in `notifications_info.xml` (simplified to the background only here):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Fifty_Percent_Black"
    android:gravity="center"
>
    <!-- Centered round-corner background, text and icon here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

I use it like so:

```
// Load the XML layout using inflater
notificationLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notifications_info, aParentView, false);
// Create the toast message
Toast notification = new Toast(App.context);
// Get the associated TextView
TextView notificationText = (TextView) notificationLayout.findViewById(R.id.Notification_Message);
// Set the text from the provided argument
notificationText.setText(aText);
// Finalize the message
notification.setView(notificationLayout);
notification.setGravity(Gravity.FILL, 0, 0);
notification.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
notification.show();
```

Everything is working as expected, except one thing... As illustrated in the following screenshot, my toast background does not cover the space where the  status and navigation bars are when not in full screen (despite the fact I set my application in fullscreen using immersive sticky mode).

[image: Top and bottom parts should be covered by toast background as well!]

Here we can see 2 brighter "bars" on top and bottom of my app, which should not be bright but with 50% translucent black layer in place (as in the rest of the screenshot). So have you an idea about how I can fix this problem please?

Have a nice day.

Comment: You want full screen or else only that center part with boarder line?

Comment: I want the darker part (50% translucent) to cover the entire screen as the yellowish does. I have my application in immersive sticky mode, which is fullscreen already (the yellow background image is covering the status and navigation bars areas already, but not the toast layout!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue but couldn't make it happen. I think the only way to do it is by changing the android source code for handling showing the Toast, see the following code from Toast.java.

```
private static class TN extends ITransientNotification.Stub {
    final Runnable mShow = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handleShow();
        }
    };

    ...
    TN() {
        // XXX This should be changed to use a Dialog, with a Theme.Toast
        // defined that sets up the layout params appropriately.
```

> this seems to me they are planning to add the feature to allow user to tweak the theme of toast, but not there yet

```
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = mParams;
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        params.windowAnimations = com.android.internal.R.style.Animation_Toast;
        params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
        params.setTitle("Toast");
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                       | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                       | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;
```

> adding the following line might be able to make toast respect the full screen mode
>
> `| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`

```
    }

    /**
     * schedule handleShow into the right thread
     */
    @Override
    public void show() {
        if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "SHOW: " + this);
        mHandler.post(mShow);
    }

    /**
     * schedule handleHide into the right thread
     */
    @Override
    public void hide() {
        if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "HIDE: " + this);
        mHandler.post(mHide);
    }

    public void handleShow() {
        if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "HANDLE SHOW: " + this + " mView=" + mView
                                  + " mNextView=" + mNextView);
        if (mView != mNextView) {
            // remove the old view if necessary
            handleHide();
            mView = mNextView;
            Context context = mView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
            String packageName = mView.getContext().getOpPackageName();
            if (context == null) {
                context = mView.getContext();
            }
            mWM = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            // We can resolve the Gravity here by using the Locale for getting
            // the layout direction
            final Configuration config = mView.getContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            final int gravity = Gravity.getAbsoluteGravity(mGravity, config.getLayoutDirection());
            mParams.gravity = gravity;
            if ((gravity & Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL) {
                mParams.horizontalWeight = 1.0f;
            }
            if ((gravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.FILL_VERTICAL) {
                mParams.verticalWeight = 1.0f;
            }
            mParams.x = mX;
            mParams.y = mY;
            mParams.verticalMargin = mVerticalMargin;
            mParams.horizontalMargin = mHorizontalMargin;
            mParams.packageName = packageName;
            if (mView.getParent() != null) {
                if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "REMOVE! " + mView + " in " + this);
                mWM.removeView(mView);
            }
            if (localLOGV) Log.v(TAG, "ADD! " + mView + " in " + this);
            mWM.addView(mView, mParams);
            trySendAccessibilityEvent();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Another option is to create you own Toast implementation using dialog or something similar, which has the following features:

1. not correspond to user touch event
2. not intercept user touch event from the window
3. will dismiss itself after a period of time
4. the showing up of multiple toasts are queued

I gave up eventually because I think it doesn't worth the effort. From user experience perspective, the use of toast is supposed to be less interruptive, but your design is for having the toast to take up the whole screen which defeat the purpose already. You might want to revisit your design: do you have to use toast? why not just simply creating a dialog which dismiss itself from user click or after a period of time?

Comment: Thanks @ChengXu for your answer, I understand the problem now... You asked why I "missuse" the toast to make it take the entire screen (which is not the toast main purpose, I agree), it is because I use it like a splash screen when my user starts a sub-activity from my main activity (which appears like a "main menu"). Anyway, as I already have a custom dialog class, I will try to implement my own "toast/splash" like dialog as you suggested in your edit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to make your application fullscreen. I think these two bright areas are for the navigation bar and status bar.

Try this method in your UI thread.

```
protected void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    |  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
}
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but my background image (which is yellowish in my screenshot) already covers the entire screen! I said I already have my application immersive sticky (which is fullscreen)... Anyway thanks for your contribution.